# access JSON of ElasticSearch in my javascript file without using PHP

Tags: javascript, html, json, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch.
I need to access the json after querying ElasticSearch from my javascript to display on my HTML page.
but constantly getting errors.
Is there any working code for this which i can use?

in code i have added "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" in head..

My code is as follows:

```
    <h1>Search Result!</h1>
    <br />
    <input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
  $("#search").click(function(e){
    var data = {
            query:{match:{_all:$('#searchterm').val()}},
            fields: '_id'
            };

            alert(JSON.stringify(data));

          $.ajax({
            url: 'server_url:9200/testindex/testindex/_search?q=*&pretty',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
           success: function(data) {
             // alert(""+JSON.parse(data.hits.total));
              $("#results").empty();
              $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + $("#searchterm").val() + "</b></p>");
              $.each(data.hits.hits, function(i,item){
                $("#results").append("<div><a href='#'>" + item._id + "</a></div>");
              });
            }
          });
        });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error message is :XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server_url:9200/testindex/testindex/_search?q=*&pretty. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://server_url' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by missing CORS headers. You can either use a proxy server, f.e. nginx to add the CORS headers or enable CORS support in Elasticsearch, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Easy insecure setup sufficient for local development:

`http.cors.enabled = true
http.cors.allow-origin = *`

Comment: Hey Thomas, Thanks for your help. Its working now. I am now configuring the way to access the json better on my HTML.